# ? value handling in Weka

Tags: machine-learning, weka, missing-data

How can I replace the '?' values in Weka.

I have a dataset. There are nominal values in a column which also have some values '?'. I tried to replace missing values with replacemissingvalues filter in Weka. This filter replaced those cells which did not have any values like blank cells but it could not replace '?'. How could I replace `?` in Weka?

[image]

Screenshot of values with `?` symbol.

Answer (score 0):

The [unofficial](https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/packages/unofficial/) Weka package [missing-values-imputation](https://github.com/fracpete/missing-values-imputation-weka-package) allows you to replace and inject missing values with various schemes.

In your case, you should be able to use the `Regex` injection scheme with `.*\?.*` as the regular expression (and `updateHeader` turned on), to replace the question marks with leading or trailing blanks (got added in release 2021.10.28).

Here is the full command-line of the `MissingValuesInjection` filter using the `Regex` injection:

```
weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.MissingValuesInjection -algorithm "weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.missingvaluesinjection.Regex -expression .*\\?.* -update-header -R first-last"
```

Answer (score -2):

Its quite bit tricky with '?' values especially if any blank spaces before or after question mark ' ?' or '? ' won't be recognized as missing values by Weka. However you can try

- At attribute level, use the option(when you right click) `Replace values with...` where you can replace '?' with blank value, prior applying missing values filter or directly replace '?' with the constant you have applied for filling the missing values.

  Sometimes the value can have blank spaces  ' ?' or '? ', so replace accordingly.

  [image]
- Use the filter `Replace with missing value` to replace '?' with blank cells. use this filter before using filter `ReplaceMissingValues` filter. However, from what I have seen you can randomly replace with missing value. Am not sure if specific values like '?', ' ?','? ' can be replaced with missing value(blank cell)

  [image]

Best method is to opt for the first one, [this you tube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nVJhPRWJAPo) provides 3 different ways to deal with missing value and shows the way how you can access `Replace values with...`